# org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException:you can't add a second 'user' criteria. Query already contains

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

when I am executing this code I am getting `org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException:Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'user' criteria. Query already contains '{ "user" : "5e269fad03f3c63845f5ca52" }'`

```
    @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;
     public List<UserTestDetails> getAllLatestTestByCompletedStatus(List<String> patientIds, String status,String typeOfTest){
            Query query=new Query();
            List<Query> queryList=new ArrayList<>();
            List<UserTestDetails> userTestDetailsList=new ArrayList<>();
         for(String patientId: patientIds) {

             if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(patientId)) {
                 query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("user").is(patientId));
             }
             if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(status)) {
                 query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("status").is(status));
             }
             if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(typeOfTest)) {
                 query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("typeOfTest").is(typeOfTest));
             }
             queryList= Arrays.asList(query);

         }
            userTestDetailsList = mongoOperations.find(query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "lastUpdated")), UserTestDetails.class);


            return userTestDetailsList;
        }
```

> As i am new to spring with mongo so I don't know where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query cannot have 2 same fields. Instead, use `$in` operator and no need to create extra `Criteria`. Use the following code:

```
@Autowired
private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

public List<UserTestDetails> getAllLatestTestByCompletedStatus(List<String> patientIds, String status, String typeOfTest){
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    if (!patientIds.isEmpty()) {
        criteria.and("user").in(patientIds);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(status)) {
        criteria.and("status").is(status);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(typeOfTest)) {
        criteria.and("typeOfTest").is(typeOfTest);
    }

    return mongoOperations.find(new Query(criteria).with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "lastUpdated")), UserTestDetails.class);
}
```

Comment: when "" mongoOperations.find(new Query(criteria).with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "lastUpdated")), UserTestDetails.class); " code get executed it gives irrelevant data. my database contains 100 records of hereditary cancer patient who has completed test status but i am getting irrelevant sets of data(more than 200 set of records)

Comment: @mkc can you post please sample data, maybe you have wrong data in database (repeated patientIds, etc...), because query has correct condition

Comment: when i cross checked into database there is only 100 sets of data and there is no any duplicate data.And when i am checking in logs then it gives repeated sets of patentId

Comment: If you dont share sample data, I can't help you. Btw: Run this: (replace to your collection name) `db.UserTestDetails.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$user", count:{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{count:-1}}])` and check if there is any repeated data

Comment: {
 "_id" : DBRef("jhi_user", ObjectId("5e1c64b203f3c65e229a54b9")),
 "count" : 346
},

/* 2 */
{
 "_id" : DBRef("jhi_user", ObjectId("5e2e866103f3c608ed98b1fb")),
 "count" : 313
},